# Word 2007 sending mail tries to use Exchange address book

Tags: thunderbird, microsoft-word-2007, exchange

My son has Office 2007 installed on Windows XP, although not Outlook - we use Thunderbird for email.  In Word 2007 when he does File / Send / E-mail, he gets an error saying that Word cannot contact an Exchange server, and then it doesn't open Thunderbird.  Thunderbird is correctly set in the Internet Options as the mail client, so why is Word trying to contact an Exchange server?

Further information:  I have now tried changing the mail client in Internet Options to Outlook Express, then changing it back to Thunderbird.  Word is still giving the same error message, which is: (I've updated the title to reflect the actual error message)

> Logon failed. You must log on to Microsoft Exchange to access your address book.
>
> Error code: "Unspecified error".

Comment: Also in Internet Options, Contact List is set to the only option, which is Address Book.  (Outlook is not an option, since it is not installed.)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe Thunderbird is not properly set as the default email client. Go to **Control Panel** -> **Internet Options** -> **Programs** and check there to see if the association is correct. Maybe that can solve the problem.

Comment: I did say in the original question that I had checked that, but when I next get to his machine I'll try changing it to something else, then changing it back.

Comment: Updated the question - I've tried changing it, and changing it back, but it didn't help.